# Get Python 2.7's 'json' to not throw an exception when it encounters random byte strings

Tags: json, google-app-engine, character-encoding, python-2.7, simplejson

Trying to serialize a dict object into a json string using Python 2.7's `json` (ie: `import json`).

```
Example:
json.dumps({
    'property1':        'A normal string',
    'pickled_property': \u0002]qu0000U\u0012
})
```

The object has some byte strings in it that are "pickled" data using `cPickle`, so for json's purposes, they are basically random byte strings. I was using django.utils's `simplejson` and this worked fine. But I recently switched to Python 2.7 on google app engine and they don't seem to have simplejson available anymore.

Now that I am using `json`, it throws an exception when it encounters bytes that aren't part of UTF-8. The error that I'm getting is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

It would be nice if it printed out a string of the character codes like the debugging might do,  ie: `\u0002]q\u0000U\u001201`. But I really don't much care how it handles this data just as long as it doesn't throw an exception and continues serializing the information that it does recognize.

How can I make this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) defines strings in terms of unicode characters. For this reason, the `json` module assumes that any `str` instance it receives holds encoded unicode text. It will try UTF-8 as its default encoding, which causes trouble when you have a string like the output of `pickle.dumps` which may not be a valid UTF-8 sequence.

Fortunately, fixing the issue is easy. You simply need to tell the `json.dumps` function what encoding to use instead of UTF-8. The following will work, even though `my_bytestring` is not valid UTF-8 text:

```
import json, cPickle as pickle

my_data = ["some data", 1, 2, 3, 4]
my_bytestring = pickle.dumps(my_data, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
json_data = json.dumps(my_bytestring, encoding="latin-1")
```

I believe that any 8-bit encoding will work in place of the `latin-1` used here (just be sure to use the same one for decoding later).

When you want to unpickle the JSON encoded data, you'll need to make a call to `unicode.decode`, since `json.loads` always returns encoded strings as `unicode` instances. So, to get the `my_data` list back out of `json_data` above, you'd need this code:

```
my_unicode_data = json.loads(json_data)
my_new_bytestring = my_unicode_data.encode("latin-1")  # equal to my_bytestring
my_new_data = pickle.loads(my_new_bytestring)          # equal to my_data
```